# PHPExcel Upload Directory Problems

Tags: php, phpexcel

I recently download PHPExcel and am liking what I have seen so far. One of my goals is to have excel files that are being worked on automatically uploaded onto our database and displayed on a webpage

I found a great link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwRPKvElM9U) on youtube that explains this but when i try to grab an excel file that is not on my local machine it doesn't load properly.

I have tested file_exists and the file can be seen normally through PHP

```
`"//test-fps/Sales/test1.xlsx"`



    <?php 

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass","server");

include ("PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");


$html = "<table border='1'>";

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("//test-fps/Sales/test1.xlsx");

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
{
    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
    for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
    {
        $html.="<tr>";
        $ticketnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$row)->getValue());
        $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$row)->getValue());
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_excel(ticketnumber, status) VALUES ('".$ticketnumber."', '".$status."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        $html.='<td>' .$ticketnumber . '</td>';
        $html.= '<td>' .$status. '</td>';
        $html.= "</tr>";
    }
}
$html .= "</table>";
echo $html;
echo '<br />Data Inserted';
?>
```

Comment: The file ___must___ exist on your local machine. You cannot load a remote file directly into PHPExcel

Comment: well that stinks, thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file ***must*** exist on your local machine. You cannot load a remote file directly into PHPExcel. This is because parsing Excel files requires the ability to use `fseek()` to move the filepointer around within the file that it is loading; and this isn't an option that is supported in remote file access, only in local file access.

Comment: and there we have it ladies & gents

Comment: Thanks again! I was searching all over to see if this was possible and now I can focus on creating a script to move the files over to the local before uploading. Cheers